# Create variable counting unique IDs in long format table

Tags: multiple-columns, data-cleaning, spss, longitudinal, long-format-data

I would like to structure my long format SPSS file so I can clean it and get a better overview. However, I run into some problems.

Patients appear several times in the database (Column patientID). How can I make a new variable that contains only 1 patient ID preferable on the line with baseline data/first moment that questionnaires are completed?

[image]

I have consulted with my colleagues, but without concrete solutions/answers

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `lag` function - after sorting the file:

```
sort cases by PatientID_Pseudo OpenInvulMomenten.
if $casenum=1 or ($casenum>1 and PatientID_Pseudo<>lag(PatientID_Pseudo)) newvar=PatientID_Pseudo.
exe.
```